# Update 12.04 (precise) to Java 7 (OpenJDK)

Tags: 12.04, java, openjdk

By default, Ubuntu 12.04 comes with OpenJDK 6, which is by now quite old and some applications require at least Java 7. How can I update an Ubuntu 12.04 installation to Java 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Ubuntu 12.04 repositories contain both version 6 and 7 of the JDK, but by default only version 6 is installed.

To update, it is best to use the Synaptic package manager – if you don’t have it, install it with
`sudo apt-get install synaptic`.

- Note: Ensure that Java 7 packages are selected before deselecting any Java 6 packages – else Synaptic will deselect anything that depends on Java (including any Java applications)!
- Search for *icedtea* and select **icedtea-7-plugin** for installation. This may select some Java 7 dependencies.
- Now search for *openjdk* and deselect **openjdk-6** as well as **openjdk-6-jre**. This may deselect some further packages.
- If you had **openjdk-6-jdk** installed, make sure it is now selected for removal and **openjdk-7-jdk** is selected for installation. (You can skip this step if **openjdk-6-jdk** is not selected, meaning it was never installed.)
- Click **Apply** and review your package selections:

  - **default-jre** packages are metapackages which are safe to remove in this process.
  - **icedtea-7-jre-cacao** is a dummy package, therefore it it OK to remove **icaedtea-6-cacao** without installing a replacement.
  - For any other Java/IcedTea 6 package that is removed, you should be installing the Java 7 equivalent.
  - Packets to be selected for removal should include the following:

    - **default-jre**
    - **default-jre-headless**
    - **icedtea-6-jre-cacao**
    - **icedtea-6-jre-jamvm**
    - **openjdk-6-jre**
    - **openjdk-6-jre-headless**
    - **openjdk-6-jre-lib**
  - Instead, the following should be installed:

    - **icedtea-7-jre-jamvm**
    - **icedtea-7-plugin**
    - **openjdk-7-jre**
    - **openjdk-7-headless**
    - **openjdk-7-lib**
- If any packages are missing, go back and select them manually. When everything is OK, install.

From a console, run `java -version`. If you have JDK installed, also run `javac -version`. Both should now report version 1.7.0.